# How to set max length of URL in angular HttpClient call to prevent CORS policy error

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

In Visual Studio 2019, solution has a Angular front end / UI project plus .NET Core projects.

I am occasionally getting the dreaded CORS error when making an HttpClient call from my Angular project to my .NET Core controller:

[image]

After much testing I realized it is caused when the request URL exceeds 512 chars. The Startup.cs file in the controller project has the CORS stuff configured:

In method ConfigureServices:

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                    builder =>
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()); 
            });
```

In method Configure, the first line is:

```
            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

How/What/Where can I allow for a larger URL string?

Here's the main code involved in my Angular project customer.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ICustomerReturn } from "../someplace";
...
...
getCustomerData(): Observable<ICustomerReturn[]> {

  const custData = {
      customerName: "John-SuperDuperReally Incredibly Long Name so we just call him john!",
      customerAddress: "1234567890\\SouthEastWestMain&NotSoMainStreet",
      customerCityState: "Providence, State of Rhode Island and Providence Plantations",
      customerZipCode: "02901"
  }
    const s1: string = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(custData));

    return this.httpClient
      .get<ICustomerReturn[]>(`https://localhost:44444/api/Customer/GetData/` + s1) 
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('got data')),
      );
};
```

The above HttpClient call will work - it will reach the Customer controller and return data. However if I add more chars to the customerName field:

```
customerName: "John-SuperDuperReally Incredibly Long Name so we just call him john!John-SuperDuperReally Incredibly Long Name so we just call him john!John-SuperDuperReally Incredibly Long Name so we just call him john!John-SuperDuperReally Incredibly Long Name so we just call him john!"
```

This when encoded produces an overall URL of over 600 chars, I get the CORS error. I've tweaked the data numerous time and that ~512 limit is what is biting me.

Comment: not sure what are you trying to achieve with this api call, are you really querying for information or want to store it into your back end? I seriously doubt someone will have a "Incredibly long name", any way if the goal is to filter results then stick to REST api design best practices, you don't have to send filtering info like that, why don't you visit https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/ for a quick reference

Comment: @Jonnathan No one will have an incredibly long name, that was just illustrative to produce the error. My actual object has 6 pieces of data, one of more of which could easily have more than 100 characters. While there are limits to each fields I cannot predict what data users will provide. Yes, I am really querying for data on the backend.

Comment: I'm quite aware you cannot predict users input, but you can set the limits, just think about it... anyways, if you still want to provide a big field for filtering I suggest to change the method to POST, so you can send a really large payload and CORS won't be a problem... this maybe do no stick to REST rules but... c'est la vie

Comment: Another developer in my company also suggested POST as a possible solution. Still I am puzzled as to this 512 boundary I am hitting, everything I've read says that GET should handle at least a 2k url for newer browsers.

Comment: Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestlinesize?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_KestrelServerLimits_MaxRequestLineSize